# Relation between tensor and hom in a specific case.

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Suppose I know that $\mbox{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(G,\mathbb{R})=0$ for a finitely generated abelian group $G$, can I then conclude that $G \bigotimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{R}=0$ too? I know that in general Hom and 'tensoring' aren't quite the same, but are the cardinalities at least equal? I came across this when working on a different problem and I would need it for my solution. If needed I can give more context. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show $G$ is a finite group (which is same as saying it is torsion )?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying! I made a question earlier on about the tensor product and its relation to torsion, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2709222/abelian-group-is-torsion-if-tensor-product-with-reals-is-zero. Can I carry over the proof that was given in the answer I got there to this case maybe? I feel like I am missing something really simple.

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for. If $G$ is a finitely generated abelian group, the structure theorem says $G=T\oplus F$ where $T$ is the torsion subgroup and $F$ a free abelian group. If $F\neq 0$, clearly $\mathrm{Hom}(F,\mathbb{R})\neq 0$ and thus $\mathrm{Hom}(G,\mathbb{R})\neq 0$.