# $A$ is the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in an algebraic number field. The residue field of $A$ wrt a prime ideal is finite.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

In Serge Lang's Algebraic Number Theory, Second Edition, Chapter 2.1 Definitions and completions, page 34,  he wrote: Let $K$ be an algebraic number field (i.e. $K$ is a  finite-dimensional extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ ), $A$ is the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$, $P\ne\{0\}$ is a prime ideal of $A$, and let $f$ be the degree of $A/P $ over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. It seems to be assumed that $A/P$ is a finite field, but why is it necessarily finite?

I know that $A$ is a Dedekin domain, hence every non-zero prime ideal is maximal, and thus $A/P$ is a field. But what did I miss to show that $A/P$ is a finite field?

Answer (score 2):

Since $A$ is finitely generated as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, we have a surjection $\mathbb{Z}^n \rightarrow A$.

Let $P$ be a prime ideal of $A$ and $p = P \cap \mathbb{Z}$, and apply $- \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}/p$, we have a surjection (since tensor product is right exact) $(\mathbb{Z}/p)^n \rightarrow A / pA$.

The left side is finite , so the right side is finite. Since $pA \subseteq P$,  there is a surjection $A / pA \rightarrow A / P$, which proves that $A/P$ is finite.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this depends on what theorems you know, but one argument goes something like this, assuming I haven't made a silly mistake:

First, putting $n := [K:\mathbb{Q}]$, recall that $A$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module of rank $n$. Now, let $P$ be a nonzero prime ideal of $A$. Since $P$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-submodule of $A$, it follows that $P$ is free of some rank $m$. If $m = n$, then $A/P$ is a torsion finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-module, hence finite, so it is sufficient to prove that $m = n$.

As you noted, $P$ is maximal, and since $A$ is an integral extension of $\mathbb{Z}$, it follows that $I := A \cap \mathbb{Z}$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$. In particular, $I$ is principal, generated by a prime $p \in \mathbb{Z}$, so we conclude $p \in P$. But then we have that $pA \subset P \subset A$, and $pA$ is clearly free of rank $n$, since it has a basis given by $\{p \cdot \alpha_{1}, \ldots, p \cdot \alpha_{n}\}$ if $\{\alpha_{1}, \ldots, \alpha_{n}\}$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis for $A$. Hence, we have $n \leqslant m \leqslant n$, so $m = n$, and we're done.

Comment: I've since had a chance to look up this argument in Pierre Samuel's lovely book "Algebraic Theory of Numbers", and my argument above over-complicates things - no need to appeal to integrality. Indeed, for any nonzero ideal $J$ of $A$, just pick $x \in J$ nonzero, and note that we have $xA \subset J \subset A$. I was worried for some reason that multiplying a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis for $A$ by $x$ might introduce $\mathbb{Z}$-linear dependencies, unlike multiplying by an honest integer. But of course, this is nonsense, since multiplication by $x$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear isomorphism $A \to xA$...

Comment: ...as it is manifestly surjective, and is injective because $A$ is a domain. Oh well, I suppose that this is what being out of practice will do to you. :)

Comment: Thanks. But why $m=n$ implies $A/P$ is torsion free? I did not work out this. (finitely generated can be proved without using $m=n$, so I assumed that "$A/P$ is torsion free" is proved by $m=n$. )

Comment: @Asigan careful - it says that $A/P$ is *torsion*, not torsion free. There might be easier ways to do this, but something like the following works: $0 \to P \to A \to A/P \to 0$ is an exact sequence of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules. $\mathbb{Q}$ is a flat $\mathbb{Z}$-module, so tensoring with $\mathbb{Q}$ gives the exact sequence $0 \to P \otimes \mathbb{Q} \to A \otimes \mathbb{Q} \to A/P \otimes \mathbb{Q} \to 0$. This is an exact sequence of $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces, and both $P \otimes \mathbb{Q}, A \otimes \mathbb{Q}$ have dimension $n$ as $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces. Since the map...

Comment: ...$P \otimes \mathbb{Q} \to A \otimes \mathbb{Q}$ is an injection, it must be an isomorphism, since they have the same dimension. It therefore follows that $A/P \otimes \mathbb{Q} = 0$, whence $A/P$ must be torsion. (If you're not familiar with this last fact, see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1190268/73817)